# Getting compressed buffer in memory in libxml2

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm using `libxml2` with `zlib` support. I'm trying to get a compressed `XML` buffer in memory. I've already tried `xmlSaveFormatFileTo()`, `xmlSaveToBuffer()` and different `xmlDocDump...()` functions. They all make buffer not compressed.

When I use `xmlSaveFormatFile()` to save the exact same compressed `xmlDoc` to a file (not to a buffer) and it saves it compressed. Is there any way at all to have a compressed buffer in memory using standard API functions? 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Compression is not (yet) supported for memory writers. See also https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxml2/devhelp/libxml2-xmlwriter.html#xmlNewTextWriterMemory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).